# XCode - Global Function self.view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

So i followed [this tutorial](http://sree.cc/iphone/global-functions-and-variables-in-objective-c) on how to create a global function..
All is working except in my global function i have a line that is:

```
[self.view addSubview:gld];
```

and i am getting an error on self.view.. any ideas?
I need the self.view part to be the view that called the function..

The Error:

> Property 'view' not found on object of type 'GlobalData*'

Comment: Sorry i have edited the line now..

Comment: It should have been `[self.view addSubView:gld];` and gld is a UILabel dynamically created by the method.

Comment: your "global" function in your "global" class wants to stick something on "self", now who is "self" for the class you are calling this function from? implement a delegate that will do the job.

Comment: Please write the function where you are adding this label.

Comment: i understand that there is no view of the class i have this function on.. but i need to know how to get the class name of the class that calls this function.. like `[CLASSTHATCALLEDTHISFUNCTION.view addSubview:gld];`

Comment: That linked tutorial is also kinda sub-optimal. There's absolutely nothing about ObjC that renders it incapable of using standard C global functions and state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you received means that the GlobalData doesn't have a property called view. Instances thant inherit from the class UIViewController have a view property. So you must be sure that GlobalData inherits from UIViewController, or any other class that has a UIView property.

**EDIT**

Now I see what you mean - but now it's clearer and you aren't using the correct nomenclature. Your method, in GlobalData, should change to:

`-(void)loadInfo:(UIView*)superView { [superView addSubview:superView]; }`

And then, you call it this way:

`[[Globaldata sharedGlobalData] loadinfo:self.view];`

Comment: i understand that there is no view of the class i have this function on.. but i need to know how to get the class name of the class that calls this function.. like [CLASSTHATCALLEDTHISFUNCTION.view addSubview:gld];

Comment: It is right there - Property 'view' not found on object of type '**GlobalData**'

Comment: 'GlobalData' isnt the one that called the function.. it is the one that the function is located in.. i have another class that calls this function like so `[[Globaldata sharedGlobalData] loadinfo];` where the "loadinfo" is the function name.. so i need the view of the class that called the function.. not the one that the function is located in.

Comment: Ok.. Now I see - but now it's clearer and you aren't using the correct nomenclature. Your method, in GlobalData, should change to:
`-(void)loadInfo:(UIView*)superView
{ [superView addSubview:superView]; }`
And then, you call it this way:
`[[Globaldata sharedGlobalData] loadinfo:self.view];`

Comment: You're welcome. But be sure you read more about how to call methods and pass parameters, **it will help you a lot** to understand what you write exactly. I suggest you read here: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Answer (score 1):

As it looks from what you posted id looks that your `GlobalData` class, that I guess is returned from `self`, is not a viewController or any other class that contains a view.

So you are basically asking

> "Please give me the view of what ever is self"  (GlobalData class I guess)

And Xcode replies:

> "Sorry but there is no view in the 'self'"

Comment: i understand that there is no view of the class i have this function on.. but i need to know how to get the class name of the class that calls this function.. like [CLASSTHATCALLEDTHISFUNCTION.view addSubview:gld];

Answer (score 1):

`self.view` refer to the super view of your app. you call the method are related to this view by "[self.view ...]" not any global function.

for calling them you should call them by their class such as

```
[MyFunctionClass Function];
```

Comment: i understand that there is no view of the class i have this function on.. but i need to know how to get the class name of the class that calls this function.. like [CLASSTHATCALLEDTHISFUNCTION.view addSubview:gld];

Comment: dude you really do not need "[Classthatcalled.view ..]" because the view that is on your screen (that you handle witch is now) is calling the function, it is important for you to add sub view, but when you do not know witch view you want to add what is the point?

Comment: you want to add a `label` to your view. but you do not know witch view is now on your screen that you add this label to that view? am i right?

Comment: correct because the label is created by the global function which isn't in the same class as the one that calls it..